# R - Issue with French accented characters

Tags: r, emacs, non-ascii-characters

Since I have updated R to 4.1.0/4.1.1 versions on W10, I have 2 problems concerning French accented characters.

- In RGui menu, accented characters are not correctly displayed [4.0.3/4.1.0 display comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n5Fh.png)
- In R console in Emacs, accented characters are also modified (with 4.1.0 but also with 4.0.3) [Print output with R4.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1iGW.png)

Is someone facing the same issues? Did you solve them?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Newb'R.

Comment: What's your `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: Hello Roman, here is lately the result of Sys.getlocale :
Sys.getlocale()
"LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252"

I have the same issue when using Python with Emacs. It must come from Emacs (although I have a lot of lines in init.el to overcome this problem (but it doesn't work ...).
Nice end of day.

Comment: I deleted all the lines with 'utf-8 like (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8) in init.el and it works now both with R and Python. I will test which line(s) lead(s) to issue. Thanks for your help. Newb'R.